# pwr.chisq.test error in R

Tags: r, error-handling, chi-squared, sample-size

I am now trying to estimate the sample size needed for A/B testing of website conversion rate. pwr.chisq.test always gives me error message, when I have small value of conversion rate:

```
# conversion rate for two groups
p1 = 0.001
p2 = 0.0011

# degree of freedom
df = 1

# effect size
w = ES.w1(p1,p2)

pwr.chisq.test(w,
               df = 1,
               power=0.8,
               sig.level=0.05)

**Error in uniroot(function(N) eval(p.body) - power, c(1 + 1e-10, 1e+05)) : 
  f() values at end points not of opposite sign**
```

However, if I have larger value for p1 and p2, this code works fine.

```
# conversion rate for two groups
p1 = 0.01
p2 = 0.011

# degree of freedom
df = 1

# effect size
w = ES.w1(p1,p2)

pwr.chisq.test(w,
               df = 1,
               power=0.8,
               sig.level=0.05)
```

> Chi squared power calculation
>
> ```
>       w = 0.01
>       N = 78488.61
>      df = 1   sig.level = 0.05
>   power = 0.8
> ```
>
> NOTE: N is the number of observations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is a "numerical" explanation to that. If you take a look at the function's code, you can see that the number of samples is computed by `uniroot` and is supposed to belong to an interval whose boundaries are set to `1e-10` and `1e5`. The error message states that this interval does not give you the result: in your case, the upper limit is too small.

Knowing that, we can simply take a wider interval:

```
w <- 0.00316227766016838
k <- qchisq(0.05, df = 1, lower = FALSE)
p.body <- quote(pchisq(k, df = 1, ncp = N * w^2, lower = FALSE))
N <- uniroot(function(N) eval(p.body) - 0.8, c(1 + 1e-10, 1e+7))$root
```

The "solution" is `N=784886.1`... that's a **huge** number of observations.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Now it works.Is "N" the minimum total sample size or the minimum sample size for each group?

Comment: According to `?pwr.chisq.test`, "`N: Total number of observations`".